# How to use regex pattern for Artifactory upload

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm using `Generic-Artifactory Integration` option to upload our artifacts to the Jfrog Artifactory as part of Jenkins build.

The format of the file to be uploaded is like - `service-api-calls-2.0.2.tar.gz` or `service-service-tmp-2.0.29.tar.gz` or `service-raw-changes-2.0.200.tar.gz`, in which, the 3rd digit is the jenkins build number and can go on till 1500.

Spec source detail,

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "**/service-*[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]+.tar.gz",
      "target": "service-repo/binaries/feature_checkout/",
      "flat" : "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

But its not matching any of the required tar.gz, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try setting regexp to true and then also escape any dots too, docs: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan : Thank you for the input.
Below is the error after escaping the dots.
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character `'*'` near index 0
`**/service-/*-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+.tar.gz`

Comment: `.*.*\/service-.*-[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+.tar.gz`

Comment: There is no point in `.*.*`. This is not an ant pattern. For a regex pattern, `.*` is enough.